# Solving HJB equation using implicit FDM

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, optimal-control, python, finite-differences

I am trying to numerically solve the following [Hamilton-Jacobi-Bellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation) (HJB) equation applied to a specifically easy value function with the implicit [finite difference method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method) (FDM). However, I get unsatisfying results but I don't know at which point the error occurs.

In my case I am considering the value function and the gain function $v, f:[0,T] \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. I will leave out the optimal control as by now I am just trying to get my code to work. I want to implement a solution to the following HJB:

$$-\frac{\partial}{\partial t}v(t,x)-(b_t-x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}v(t,x)-\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}v(t,x)-f(t,x)=0$$

with terminal condition $v(T,x)=0$, where

$$dX_t=  (b_t-X_t)dt + \sigma dW_t, \qquad W_t\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

is a mean-reverting process with forecast $b_t$. Setting $v(t,x)=tx^2$ this leads to

$$f(t,x)=-x^2-(b_{t}-x)2tx-t\sigma^2$$

The implicit method is obtained by the forward method as I am solving the value function backwards in time. Therefore, I should not worry about stability concerns. Also I use the backward finite difference instead of the central finite difference method for the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ term. The HJB would therefore translate into

\begin{align}
-\frac{v_i^{t_n}-v_{i}^{t_{n-1}}}{\Delta t}&=\frac{\sigma^2}{2}\frac{v_{i+1}^{t_{n-1}}-2v_{i}^{t_{n-1}}+v_{i-1}^{t_{n-1}}}{h^2}+(b_{t_{n-1}}-x_i)\frac{v_{i}^{t_{n-1}}-v_{i-1}^{t_{n-1}}}{h}+f(t_{n-1}, x_i)\\
\iff v_i^{t_n} &= -\Delta t \big((\frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}-\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_i}{h})v_{i-1}^{t_{n-1}}-(\frac{\sigma^2}{h^2}+\frac{1}{\Delta t}-\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_i}{h})v_{i}^{t_{n-1}}+\frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}v_{i+1}^{t_{n-1}}+f(t_{n-1}, x_i)\big)
\end{align}

with discretization of the domain of interest $[0,T]\times[a,b], a<b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a=x_0,\dots,x_N=b, x_i = x_0 + ih$ and $0=t_0, t_1, \dots, t_M=T, t_i=t_0+i\Delta t$.

As I want to check consistency for the true value function, e.g. $v(t,x)=tx^2$ the boundary values for $v(t_n, a)$ and $v(t_n, b)$ are known. My Pseudo goes as follows:

> Store true boundary values of $v$ into arrays $v_a$ and $v_b$ (thus being of length $[0,\dots,T]$)\
> for $t_n$ in $[T,\dots,t_1]$: # $t_1$ instead of $t_0=0$ in order to not overstep last iteration\
> Initiate $v$ to be zero matrix with corresponding rows and columns\
> Solve
> $$\left( {\begin{array}{ccc}
>     -\frac{\sigma^2}{h^2}-\frac{1}{\Delta t}+\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_1}{h} & \frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}  &\\
> \frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}-\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_2}{h} & \ddots & \frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2} \\
> & \frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}-\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_{N-1}}{h} & -\frac{\sigma^2}{h^2}-\frac{1}{\Delta t}+\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_{N-1}}{h}  \end{array} } \right)
> \left({\begin{array}{c}
> v_1^{t_{n-1}}\\
> \vdots \\
> v_{N-1}^{t_{n-1}}\\
> \end{array}}\right)= -\frac{1}{\Delta t}
> \left({\begin{array}{c}
> v_1^{t_n}\\
> \vdots \\
> v_{N-1}^{t_n}\\
> \end{array}}\right)-
> \left({\begin{array}{c}
> f(t_{n-1}, x_1)+(\frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}-\frac{b_{t_{n-1}}-x_1}{h})v_a^{t_{n-1}}\\
> \vdots \\
> f(t_{n-1}, x_{N-1})+\frac{\sigma^2}{2h^2}v_b^{t_{n-1}}\\
> \end{array}}\right)$$
> Glue $v_a, v, v_b$ together

This is my code so far

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as st
import scipy.sparse as spa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np


T = 3
d_t = 0.25
t_grid = np.arange(0, T+d_t, d_t)

prodmax = 6
consmax = 6
h = 0.2
x_grid = np.arange(-prodmax, consmax+h, h)

b = np.zeros(len(t_grid))
sig = 0.1

for i, t in enumerate(t_grid):
    if i==0:
        b[0] = 0
    else:
        b[i] = b[i-1]+(6*np.sin(np.pi*t_grid[i-1])-b[i-1])*d_t

v_true = np.zeros((len(t_grid), len(x_grid)))

for l, t in enumerate(t_grid):
    for i, x in enumerate(x_grid):
        v_true[l,i] = t*x**2

va_store = v_true[:, 0]
vb_store = v_true[:, -1]
va_store[-1], vb_store[-1] = 0, 0

v_fdm = np.zeros((len(t_grid), len(x_grid[1:-1])))

for l, t in enumerate(t_grid[1:]):
    
    # iteration backwards in time,  attention between l and 1
    l_back = len(t_grid)-1-l
    
    # Create finite difference matrix with truncated domain as we now have boundary conditions
    up_diag = sig**2/h**2/2*np.ones(len(x_grid[1:-2]))
    diag = -sig**2/h**2 - 1/d_t + (b[l_back-1]-x_grid[1:-1])/h
    low_diag = sig**2/h**2/2+(b[l_back-1]-x_grid[2:-1])/h

    # Evaluate and update gain function
    f = np.array([-x**2-(b[l_back-1]-x)*2*t*x-t*sig**2 for x in x_grid[1:-1]])
    f[0] = f[0] + (sig**2/h**2/2-(b[l_back-1]-x_grid[1])/h)*va_store[l_back-1]
    f[-1] = f[-1] + sig**2/h**2/2*vb_store[l_back-1]
    
    A = np.diag(up_diag, k=1) + np.diag(diag, k=0) + np.diag(low_diag, k=-1)
    v_fdm[l_back-1, :] = np.linalg.solve(A, -v_fdm[l_back, :]/d_t-f)

v_fdm = np.column_stack((np.column_stack((va_store, v_fdm)), vb_store))

# Create 3D surface plot
T, X = np.meshgrid(t_grid, x_grid)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=X, y=T, z=v_fdm.T)])

# Customize plot
fig.update_traces(colorscale='Viridis')
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis_title='x', yaxis_title='t', zaxis_title='v_fdm(t,x)'))

# Show plot
fig.show()
```

However, running this code leads to [image]

instead of something close to [image]

I hope you can help me out on this one.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~mitchell/ToolboxLS/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone has the same issue, I implemented the second part of the algorithm correctly. In this case I went for a central finite difference method for the $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ term

````
v_fdm_HJB = np.zeros((len(t_grid), len(x_grid)))
v_fdm_HJB[:, 0] = v_true[:, 0]
v_fdm_HJB[:, -1] = v_true[:, -1]
v_fdm_HJB[-1, 1:-1] = v_true[-1, 1:-1] # Terminal condition

# Initiate Components of Finite Difference Matrix
up_diag = np.ones(len(x_grid[1:-2]))
diag = -2*np.ones(len(x_grid[1:-1]))
low_diag = np.ones(len(x_grid[2:-1]))
A = np.diag(up_diag, k=1) + np.diag(diag, k=0) + np.diag(low_diag, k=-1)
C = np.diag(up_diag, k=1) - np.diag(low_diag, k=-1)

for n, t in enumerate(t_grid[1:]):    
    # iteration backwards in time
    n_back = len(t_grid)-1-n
    
    # Create Finite Difference Matrix
    eu = np.diag(b[n_back-1]-x_grid[1:-1])
    M = np.eye(len(x_grid[1:-1]))-d_t*sig**2/2/h**2*A-d_t/(2*h)*eu@C
    
    # forcing term for v(t,x)=t*x**2
    f = np.array([-x**2-t_grid[n_back-1]*sig**2-2*(b[n_back-1]-x)*x*t_grid[n_back-1] for x in x_grid[1:-1]])
            
    # Include boundary conditions
    f[0] = f[0] + (sig**2/2/h**2-(b[n_back-1]-x_grid[1])/(2*h))*v_fdm_HJB[n_back-1, 0]
    f[-1] = f[-1] + (sig**2/2/h**2+(b[n_back-1]-x_grid[-2])/(2*h))*v_fdm_HJB[n_back-1, -1]
    
    # Update value function
    v_fdm_HJB[n_back-1, 1:-1] = np.linalg.solve(M, v_fdm_HJB[n_back, 1:-1]+d_t*f)

# Create 3D surface plot
T, X = np.meshgrid(t_grid, x_grid)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=X, y=T, z=(v_true-v_fdm_HJB).T)])
#fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(x=X, y=T, z=v_fdm_HJB.T)])

# Customize plot
fig.update_traces(colorscale='Viridis')
fig.update_layout(scene=dict(xaxis_title='x', yaxis_title='t', zaxis_title='v(t,x)'))

# Show plot
#fig.show(renderer="browser")
fig.show()
```
````